# Modern Java GUI

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm writing a little program with Java and it would be cool if it looked a bit more modern. I want something that looks like websites, or apps flat, colorful buttons, lots of white space, looking neat and simple. Something like this: 
http://www.the-webdesign.net/freebie-28-kostenlose-psd-user-interfaces/ 
(To avoid confusion: I'm not writing a website, it is a private, offline programm, meant to help me planning role play games. Essentially I'm writing it to learn something about Java)
 I've read some questions that sounded like mine, but found nothing quite fitting. There are the very simple answers concerning look and feels. I've checked that out, but I don't think thats what I want (or maybee it is, and I've just not found the right one? Maybee you can recommend one). And the really complicated ones, mentioning programs or whatever I've never head about, and I'm not sure thats still Java, but I'm quite sure it's to complicated for me. 
So what I would like to know: is there a (not more than moderatly challenging) Java solution to do what I want? (If so, what is it?^^)

Comment: Get yourself PhotoShop and start making images.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean.

Comment: You want good looking images in your program. You can make them yourself in PhotoShop.

Comment: No you missunderstood my question. (So much, that I doubt you even read the heading) I want the program itself to look good. I dont mention images, no even once.

Comment: So you want to change the appearance of what then? Buttons? Lines? Fonts? If you want whitespace just add padding to your gui elements. You want a colorful button? Make a picture/image and set it as the background for the button. Maybe you could post a picture of what you expect to make.

Comment: All GUI elements. I dont want that oldfashioned look of the standard look and feel. I did. On the website I posted there are pictures of web interfaces, I want my desktop interface to look a like that.

Comment: I read the question; you're asking how you can get your programs to look samples in the link. How is it you think custom components are made? If the ones provided, or found, cannot suit your means, you *will* be making images. A button is a button, it's background is what makes it special.

Comment: But the standard button is edgy with a 3D effect, I can't get that away with a background. And How would I change the look of a radiobutton, or checkbox, with a image? all I can change there is the space next to it, the checkbox itself will allways look the same.

Comment: Your getting a bit advanced for "learning java" however if your interested you should look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/

Comment: Thanks. I came accros that page, before I posted the question. So all I could do would be modifing everything myself? I thought, and you obviously do as well, that this is a bit much for a beginner. ^^ I hoped for an easier solution, but I'd be as satisfied, if someone could tell me for sure, that what I want can not be done quick and easy.

Comment: @Soronume Quick and easy is subjective.  Some one with experience might suggest that it is, some one without the experience might say it's not.  You will need to decide if the amount of work involved is worth the effort for the results you want to achieve.  None the less, it is a detailed amount of work, as you need to be able to provide the flexibility you want to achieve the results you want at the design time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a number of choices, but it will depend on which frame work you wan to use...

### Swing

You could:

- Modify the look and feel properties of an existing look and feel to meet your needs
- Create your own look and feel to meet your needs
- Skin a look and feel using the Synthetic look and feel.
- Provide custom painted elements as required...

Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html

### Java FX

Allows you to "skin" the look and feel via the use of CSS.

See [Skinning JavaFX Applications with CSS](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm) for more details

### Passing thoughts

A "modern" looking application is a subjective thing.  Users have predefined concepts of what an application should look like and how and application should work and the controls that should be used to achieve these results.

I would, personally, focus on usability as a primary goal and the look and feel as a secondary goal.  Don't put form over function, it will always bite you in the rear in the end

Comment: "_focus on usability as a primary goal and the look and feel as a secondary goal_" Totally agree, especially considering the OP himself said "_it is a private, offline programm, meant to help me planning role play games_". How it looks makes no difference.

Comment: In general I agree. But it is more complicated here, as the function and the goal are different things here, 
As I said, its primary use is to learn something about Java. Right now I want to learn how I could make my program look good. So looking good is its primary use for now. ;-)

Comment: @Soronume Just remember, design is kick.  When "re-thinking" a user interface, you will want to spend plenty of time designing the interactions between the different elements, knowing how the fit together, how best they can be used and how the user might interact with them.  There is more to just "skinning" the interface, there is also the layout and the conditions under which elements should be used and the navigation between contexts to be considered...just saying ;)